# ABAP Alv Cell size with tooltip

Tags: abap, alv

In my ALV I have several cells, some cells contain other icons and tooltips without content,

However when I try to put a letter in the cell, the cell takes an obscure error size in the occurrence of the tooltip text, here is my code to fill the cell.

I use the icon @SPACE\Q@  to put a tooltip

This is my code :

```
*   Si une livraison ete planifie et a ete reculee.
              ELSEIF ls_plcd2-dlivr GT ls_plcd2-dlivp.
                CONCATENATE   '@B_SPCE\Q' text-t13  '  ' ls_plcd2-dlivr+6(2) '/' ls_plcd2-dlivr+4(2) '/' ls_plcd2-dlivr+0(4)  '@M' INTO  <value> RESPECTING BLANKS.
*                CONCATENATE   '@DENOCO\Q' text-t13  '  ' ls_plcd2-dlivr+6(2) '/' ls_plcd2-dlivr+4(2) '/' ls_plcd2-dlivr+0(4)  '@' INTO  <value> RESPECTING BLANKS.
                ls_colcl-color-col  = gc_liprc+0(1).
                ls_colcl-color-int  = gc_liprc+1(1).
                ls_colcl-color-inv  = gc_liprc+2(1).
                APPEND ls_colcl TO lt_colcl.

                CONCATENATE 'ls_tbxcl-' ls_plani-fldnm INTO lv_value.
                ASSIGN (lv_value) TO <value>.
                <value>           = text-t17. " Texte Livraison reculee pour Excel

*             Si une livraison ete planifie pour cette date et elle a ete avancee.
              ELSEIF ls_plcd2-dlivr LT ls_plcd2-dlivp.
                CONCATENATE   '@B_SPCE\Q' text-t14 '  ' ls_plcd2-dlivr+6(2) '/' ls_plcd2-dlivr+4(2) '/' ls_plcd2-dlivr+0(4)  '@M' INTO  <value> RESPECTING BLANKS.
*                CONCATENATE   '@DENOCO\Q' text-t14 '  ' ls_plcd2-dlivr+6(2) '/' ls_plcd2-dlivr+4(2) '/' ls_plcd2-dlivr+0(4)  '@' INTO  <value> RESPECTING BLANKS.
*                <value>           = text-t05.
                ls_colcl-color-col  = gc_lipav+0(1).
                ls_colcl-color-int  = gc_lipav+1(1).
                ls_colcl-color-inv  = gc_lipav+2(1).
                APPEND ls_colcl TO lt_colcl.
```

Screen-Copy :

[image]